# Concatenating Numpy arrays for OpenCV imshow

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

Using OpenCV and Python, I want to display the left hand half of one image concatenated with the right-hand half of another image, both of the same size - 512x512 pixels. I have identified several ways of doing this, but I am confused about the behaviour of one method. In the following code, assume that only one of the methods is used at any one time and the rest are commented out:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image1 = cv2.imread('img1.png',0)
image2 = cv2.imread('img2.png',0)

#Method 1 - works
image3 = np.concatenate([image1[:,0:256], image2[:,256:512]], axis=1)

#Method 2 - works
image3 = image1[:,:]
image3[:,256:512] = image2[:,256:512]

#Method 3 - works if I don't create image3 with np.zeros first. 
#Otherwise displays black image - all zeros - but print displays correct values
image3 = np.zeros(shape=(512,512), dtype=int)
image3[:,0:256] = image1[:,0:256]
image3[:,256:512] = image2[:,256:512]
print(image3)

cv2.imshow("IMAGE", image3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In method 3, I at first mistakenly thought that the new numpy array image 3 would need to be created first and so created an array filled with zeros and then seemingly overwrote that array with the correct values. When I print that array it displays the correct values, but when I show it as an image using cv2.imshow it is all black (i.e. all zeros). Why the difference? I understand that slicing creates a view, not a copy, but can someone please explain what is happening in method 3 and why cv2.imshow displays the underlying array but print doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in:

```
np.zeros(shape=(512,512), dtype=int)
```

`imshow` will show images coded as float(32 bit) with a range of 0.-1. or 8bit(1-4 channels) with a range of 0-255. You are using int, which is 32 bit (in most cases) and it is not a floating point. What you should do to fix it, is to use `np.uint8`.

```
np.zeros(shape=(512,512), dtype=np.uint8)
```

I think also it can be displayed using `matplotlib` if you want to keep the `int`, but I am not 100% sure about it.